# Inconsistent hyperlink colors on Meta

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks

In Meta, the hyperlinks are colored inconsistently in the profile, as compared to other parts of the site.

---

On the profile (activity) page, the colors are a reddish-brown:

[image: profile activity links]

---

In the [post comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/80623#comment678988_80623), or as you can see in this sentence's link, the colors are gray:

[image: page comment links]

---

The colors are consistent in the Stack Overflow site, but I was too lazy to check all of other sites in the Stack Exchange network. Sorry.